# Newbie - Having trouble installing USB WIFI adapter 22.10 Realtek RTL8812BU

Tags: wireless, realtek, adapter

I have a problem with installation driver to my WiFi adapter(Realtek RTL8812BU). I followed instructions on this https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702/blob/main/README.md

What I got in console on last step(when I need Run the installation script (install-driver.sh)):

A required package appears to not be installed.

Please install the following package: iw

Once the package is installed, please run "sudo ./install-driver.sh"

---

What is package "iw" and how can i fix it? Big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[iw](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/iw) is a "tool for configuring Linux wireless devices".

Install it with `sudo apt install iw`.

Comment: Oh my god!!BIG THANKS!!! That works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!